# Git Pull for All Branches

Tags: git, github

so I'm new to Git and had a question about updating my branches after code has been pushed to the master branch. If I have my `master`, `branch A`, `branch B` branches in my local machine, and a a master branch with new commits on the GitHub repo, how can I update all 3 of my branches?

Do I need to do `git pull` in all 3 branches (a followup, if I do git pull in all of the branches, when I make a pull request for `branch A`, will all the files already in the `master` branch that I pulled also show up in the PR? How can I avoid this?)

Thanks!

Comment: No way to truly automate this, no. You'll have to update each branch successively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if I got you correct, you branched away from `master` resulting in `branch A` and `branch B`. In meanwhile there are changes in `master` which you would like to [Rebase](https://docs.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/using-git/about-git-rebase). So you would basically checkout `branch A` and then run a rebase as suggested in the link

```
git checkout B
git rebase --interactive master
```

This would add the new commits of `branch B` on top of what you have in `master`. See also the picture from https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing

[image: graphic representation of rebase]

After that you have to [force push](https://docs.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/using-git/using-git-rebase-on-the-command-line#pushing-rebased-code-to-github) the changes to the remote repo.

> Force pushing has serious implications because it changes the historical sequence of commits for the branch. Use it with caution, especially if your repository is being accessed by multiple people.

Comment: So if I rebase, all the changes to master will be added to my branch ontop of changes already prexisting to my branch. So when I make a PR, will all the rebased changes also show up in the PR? I'd like to avoid this since they're already in the master branch

Comment: No you rebase your branches i.e. you take master and add the changes of the feature branches on top of it. I've added a graphic which shows you what rebase means

Comment: Ohh ok thanks so much! So rebasing is the way to go. Is the `--interactive` necessary or can I just run git rebase master or git rebase origin master in the branch? So if I understand right, I can rebase, continue my changes, then push to the remote repo and only feature changes (not rebased changes) will show up in a PR

Comment: yes that's right. and no `--interactive` is not necessary